# Prediction error after mean-centring/transforming/etc. input data?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, linear, error-propagation

Suppose that I have a linear model of $p$ parameters ($f(p,x)$) that I want to fit to my dataset using least squares. According to Wolberg (2006), the prediction error in $\hat{y}$ can be calculated from the covariance matrix of the fit, $C$, using:

$$
\sigma_{f}^{2} = \sum_{j=0}^{j=n} \sum_{k=0}^{k=n} \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{p_{j}}} \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{p_{k}}} C_{j,k}
$$

(where $n$ is the size of $p$)

For a simple linear function $y = a + bx$, $\sigma_{f}$ using the above relation becomes:

$$
\sigma_{f}^{2} = \sigma_{a}^{2} + \sigma_{b}^{2} x^{2} + 2x\sigma_{a,b}^{2}
$$

But what happens if I want to mean-centre or otherwise transform $x$ before the fit, in order to account for issues like heteroscedasticity? How would these processes affect $\sigma_{f}$, given that they carry their own inherent uncertainties?

Let's take mean-centring as an example. My simple linear function becomes:

$$
y = a + b(x-\bar{x})
$$

Assuming that I can use the standard error of the mean here for $\sigma_{\bar{x}}$, I could plug this into Wolberg's relation and get a new definition for $\sigma_{f}$:

$$
\sigma_{f}^{2} = \sigma_{a}^{2} + \sigma_{\bar{x}}^{2} b^{2} + \sigma_{b}^{2} (\bar{x} - x)^{2} + 2x\sigma_{a,b}^{2}
$$

(I'm making the assumption here that there is negligible covariance between $\bar{x}$ and $a$ or $b$. Is this right?)

After playing around with this new definition of $\sigma_{f}$ with some test data, I've found that $\sigma_{f}$ increases considerably if even a little noise is present in $x$. This suggests to me that mean-centring (or indeed any transformation applied to $x$) seems not worthwhile if the goal is to predict $\hat{y}$ with a reasonable $\sigma_{f}$. What am I missing here?

**Reference:**

Wolberg, J., Data Analysis Using the Method of Least Squares, 2006, Springer

Comment: A simple linear of affine transformation like mean-centering should not change the predictions of a linear model. // Such a conversation warrants a separate question, but what heteroskedasticity issue do you aim to fix by transforming the features?

Comment: @Dave: I'm not arguing that the prediction itself would change, but that the act of mean-centring introduces additional uncertainty to the prediction, unless there's something I'm missing here? Do we include the mean-centring in the error propagation as in my example, or not? // I was referring to methods like log-transforming x to stabilise the variance, but the partial derivatives for that are messy and I didn't want to make this post too large. Let's please focus on the mean-centring issue as that's hopefully easier to discuss here.

Comment: In words, what is $\sigma_f$ if it is not the standard deviation of the (common) error term? (Or is that what it is?)

Comment: @Dave: I think your definition is correct